# double the stone puzzle

Tags: story, calculation-puzzle

**Story:**

I've `x` number of stones. On my way, I will cross three wells. When I reach a well, then I will throw `y` number of stones into the well. After that, remaining stones are twice the count....

> **eg:**
>
> If I have 5 stones and I dropped 3 stones into the well. Now remaining 2 
>   stones are twice the count. So I have 4 stones, while leaving the well.

It is continues to all well crossing. At end of travel, I have `zero` number of stones.

**Puzzle:**

What is the value of `x+y`?

**Note:**

Same number of stones must be dropped into the wells.

**Hint:**

> Solve the puzzle as backwards. Because, there we have a value as `zero`.

Comment: "After that, remaining stones are twice the count...." ?

Comment: when leaving the well, the remaining stone's count is twice..

Comment: twice than $y$ and/or how many stone you throw in a well?

Comment: After throwing `y` number of stones, then I have `2(x-y)` number of stones. Beside, I update my question with an example. Kindly take look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, every time you throw $y$ amount of stones into a well, at the end the number of stones you have becomes as twice as before, for example let's say we have $x$ amount of stones, if I throw $y$ amount of stones, then I am supposed to have $x-y$ stones left, but magically it becomes $2x-2y$ stones. So what happens if I visit 3 wells and I end up with zero stones after I throw the last $y$ amount of stones.

After revisiting the original question, let's solve it:

Well 1

> I had x stones, I threw $y$ stones, I was supposed to have $x-y$ stones then magically I ended up $2x-2y$ stones with $y$ stones in the well.

Well 2

> I had $2x-2y$ stones, I threw $y$ stones, I was supposed to have $2x-3y$ stones then magically I ended up $4x-6y$ stones with $y$ stones in the well.

Well 3

> I had $4x-6y$ stones, I threw $y$ stones, and I should not have more stones.

As a result

> $4x-6y=y$ and $4x=7y$

So the minimum number of stones that you can carry

> could be $x=7$ and $y=4$. So $x+y=11$ stones.

if I understand it correctly of course.

Comment: what a man....!!